# Setting up libvirt with remote access on gentoo: not listening tls port

Tags: gentoo, tls, libvirt, virt-manager

I'm trying to set up libvirtd on my headless gentoo server. I'd like to have remote control via tls. I've followed libvirt remote access guide, but it don't work for me: client virt-manager shows following error:

```
unable to connect to libvirtd at 'xxx.xxx.info': Connection refused

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1055, in _try_open
    None], flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 107, in openAuth
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirtError: unable to connect to libvirtd at 'xxx.xxx.info': Connection refused
```

Here is my current server libvirtd config (comments stripped):

```
listen_tls = 1 
tls_port = "16514"
auth_tls = "none"
tls_no_verify_address = 1
```

And it does not listens to port 16514: `lsof -i tcp:16514` prints nothing.

I also have following in my log just after libvirtd start:

```
Mar 30 14:46:02 fs dnsmasq[27523]: started, version 2.52 cachesize 150
Mar 30 14:46:02 fs dnsmasq[27523]: compile time options: no-IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus I18N DHCP no-TFTP
Mar 30 14:46:02 fs dnsmasq-dhcp[27523]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.122.2 -- 192.168.122.254, lease time 1h
Mar 30 14:46:02 fs dnsmasq[27523]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Mar 30 14:46:02 fs dnsmasq[27523]: using nameserver 192.168.1.3#53
Mar 30 14:46:02 fs dnsmasq[27523]: bad address at /etc/hosts line 2
Mar 30 14:46:02 fs dnsmasq[27523]: read /etc/hosts - 15 addresses
Mar 30 14:46:10 fs kernel: IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:18:82:ed:d1:df:08:00 SRC=172.28.36.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=62606 PROTO=2 
Mar 30 14:46:33 fs kernel: IN=virbr0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:26:a8:55:dc:5f:05:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

"kernel: IN=virbr0" are dropped packets logged by -j LOG rule in my iptables config. However, I've tried with all iptables rules allowed - nothing changed.

Certs seems to be fine as well (maybe not?):

```
# ls -R /etc/pki/
/etc/pki/:
CA  libvirt

/etc/pki/CA:
ca.info  cacert.pem  cakey.pem

/etc/pki/libvirt:
private  servercert.pem

/etc/pki/libvirt/private:
server.info  servercert.pem  serverkey.pem
```

I'm on gentoo running

```
[ebuild   R   ] app-emulation/libvirt-0.8.8-r1  USE="json libvirtd lvm lxc network nls parted python qemu udev virt-network -avahi -caps -debug -iscsi -macvtap -nfs -numa -openvz -pcap -phyp -policykit -sasl (-selinux) -uml -virtualbox -xen" 0 kB
```

libvirtd is running:

```
# ps ax | grep [v]irt
30484 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/sbin/libvirtd -d
30735 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/libvirt/network/default.pid --conf-file=  --except-interface lo --listen-address 192.168.122.1 --dhcp-range 192.168.122.2,192.168.122.254 --dhcp-lease-max=253 --dhcp-no-override
```

Anything else I should check. How do I debug this issue?

**SOLVED**:

I'd run libvirtd with --lsiten flag. It's possible to specify it in `/etc/conf.d/libvirtd` file.
Also, I've found another error in my configuration: when adding connection in virt-manager, you must specify an hypervisor, so url would look like `quemu+tsl://user@host/system`, not just `quemu+tsl://user@host/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting point of your investigation should be here :

> And it does not listens to port 16514: lsof -i tcp:16514 prints nothing

This is quite a low level issue : the daemon does not listen on the tcp port.

You should check for any log messages that could indicate an error, or launch the daemon manually in a terminal to see what it says...

Comment: The problem that it does not prints any messages to logs or stdout even when launching from console with -v flag.

Comment: Oh... There is --listen switch, that should be specified for libvirt to listen network. You've not answered my question, but forced me to run libvirtd with --help. Thanks!

Comment: well, actually, sort of. Would you have run the daemon as executable if I didn't suggested it? ;)